# Cython boundscheck & nonecheck

Tags: python, numpy, cython

I struggle for several day with a script giving me unexpected results. 
Today, I just realize that if I used a cython function with or without `boundscheck` and `nonecheck` decorators, I do not obtain the same results !

Here is an example :

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython

cdef double[4] c
c[0] = 0.1
c[1] = 0.2
c[2] = 0.3
c[3] = 0.4


def cp1(double[:,::1] u, double[:,::1] K, int ixmin, int ixmax, int izmin, int izmax):
    cpc1(u, K, ixmin, ixmax, izmin, izmax)


def cp2(double[:,::1] u, double[:,::1] K, int ixmin, int ixmax, int izmin, int izmax):
    cpc2(u, K, ixmin, ixmax, izmin, izmax)


@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.nonecheck(False)
cdef void cpc1(double[:,::1] u, double[:,::1] K, int ixmin, int ixmax, int izmin, int izmax) nogil:

    cdef Py_ssize_t ix, iz
    cdef double dpu, dmu

    for ix in range(ixmin+2, ixmax-1):
        for iz in range(izmin, izmax):
            dpu = c[0]*u[ix-1, iz] + c[1]*u[ix, iz] + c[2]*u[ix+1, iz]
            dmu = c[1]*u[ix-1, iz] + c[2]*u[ix, iz] + c[3]*u[ix+1, iz]
            K[ix, iz] = 0.5*dpu - 0.5*dmu

@cython.boundscheck(True)
@cython.nonecheck(True)
cdef void cpc2(double[:,::1] u, double[:,::1] K, int ixmin, int ixmax, int izmin, int izmax) nogil:

    cdef Py_ssize_t ix, iz
    cdef double dpu, dmu

    for ix in range(ixmin+2, ixmax-1):
        for iz in range(izmin, izmax):
            dpu = c[0]*u[ix-1, iz] + c[1]*u[ix, iz] + c[2]*u[ix+1, iz]
            dmu = c[1]*u[ix-1, iz] + c[2]*u[ix, iz] + c[3]*u[ix+1, iz]
            K[ix, iz] = 0.5*dpu - 0.5*dmu
```

If I run these lines :

```
u = np.random.rand(256, 256)
K1 = np.zeros_like(u)
K2 = np.zeros_like(u)

cp1(u, K1, 100, 150, 100, 150)
cp2(u, K2, 100, 150, 100, 150)
```

the instruction `np.all(K1 == K2)` returns `False`. The difference between the two arrays is close to the machine precision (about 5e-17) but using this function thousand of times is enough to give me large differences on the final results.

Now, if remove the `nogil` instructions in `cpc1` and `cpc2` and I replace `cdef double[4] c` by `c = np.zeros(4)`, both `cp1` and `cp2` functions return the same results. The problem is that I lose about 50% performance using `ndarray` instead of `c array`.

In think the problem comes from the c array precision, but why the value of `boundscheck` and `nonecheck` have an impact on the results in this case (no access out of bounds, no none, ...)

Is there a way to solve this ?

**EDIT**

As highlighted by ead, if I compile the code without `-03 --ffast-math -march=native`, both `cp1` and `cp2` return the same results ! But at the cost of doubling the execution time ! I can more or less understand why `O3` and `ffast-math` lead to unexpected results doing aggressive optimizations, but I don't undertand why `march=native` also *breaks* the code.

Is there a way to preserve both performance and precision ?

Comment: FWIW, I always get the same result (Windows+MSVC). Do you use `fastmath` while compiling the C code?

Comment: Yes ! I use -O3 -ffast-math -march=native

Comment: 1) If this is just an array precision error then why does it matter? You don't really have any way of knowing which answer is closer to "right". 2) I suspect this issue with using a numpy array for C is to do with looking up global variables. If you do `cdef double[::1] c_local = c` at the start of the function and then it should be quicker

Comment: `cdef double[::1]` can only be used with `gil`. I gave it a try, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: I'm pretty sure, this behavior is due to `-ffast-math`: without bound-check some optimizations become feasible which are not ieee-74 conformant but are allowed to do due to `-ffast-math`. You should use `-ffast-math´ only if you really know what you are doing.

Comment: Yes `ffast-math` but also `march=native`

Comment: I see differences when compiled with `-O3 -ffast-math`, but not when compiled with `-O3 -march=native`. Tried with gcc-7, gcc-5 and clang-5.

Comment: You must be aware, that for some build-pipelines, changing compiler-flags doesn't trigger the rebuild of the extension and you might still be using the one compiled with `-ffast-math`.